# gulp-load-plugin not recognizing util.log

Tags: gulp

With following gulpfile.js i am getting error "Cannot read property 'log' of undefined"

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var args = require('yargs').argv;

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy:true});



gulp.task('vet',function(){
    log('Analyzing source with JSHint and JSCS');
    return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.js','./*.js'])
        .pipe($.if(args.verbose,$.print()))
        .pipe($.jscs())
        .pipe($.jshint())
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish',{verbose:true}))
        .pipe($.jshint.reporter('fail'));
});

function log(msg){
    if(typeof(msg)==='object'){
        for(var item in msg){
            if(msg.hasOwnProperty(item)){
                $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg[item]));
            }
        }
    } else {
        $.util.log($.util.colors.blue(msg));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ok i sovled my problem but the solution is kind of surprising for me. I was previously using various other gulp plugins like gulp-util, gulp-jscs, gulp-if etc, then i decided to use gulp-load-plugins and i thought when i am using this i can just remove all my plugins from package.json files, thats when the problem started happening. You MUST NOT remove your plugins from your package.json file otherwise you will get same error like i was getting it. I am still not sure why removing these plugins from pacakge.json, is causing this issue ??

Comment: The problem is `gulp-load-plugins` will read your package.json file to make a list of gulp plugins and pre-load them. Removing an package from package.json will cause problem even it 's still existing in node_modules.